# VS 2013 Go back to one tab group?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When switching to a splitted screen, using groups tabs, is there an easy way to get back to a single tab?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do it in one single step for all tabs, but you can drag each individual tab (by clicking in the tab name area) and drop it in the desired group.

Comment: I'm looking for a way that I can make a shortcut or make a command to automize that.

Answer (score 2):

The `Window > Windows` menu option will show a dialog box with the open windows, which you can use to select windows to close. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to the `Window.Windows` command.

Another option is to use the `Window > Close All Documents` menu option. or assign a keyboard shortcut to `Windows.CloseAllDocuments` command.

None of the above do exactly what you want, but they can save you a lot of clicking around.

Comment: Maybe I can write a macro to store all windows' paths in a variable, close all windows, and reopen all windows, which will probably open in a single tab group.